# C# Paste xml as class : Missing stylesheet

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, serialization

I am using .NETCore and Visual Studio 2019.

I have a xml file that starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../someString/stylesheet/someString-xsl.xsl"?>
```

The problem is that when I use Visual Studio to auto generate the class from the xml file, those two lines are ignored.

Without the first line, any generated xml-file I generate violates the standard I have to adhere to and without the second line XMLDocument.load() will give me an error if I read anything but a self-generated class.

Does anyone know how to add these two lines to the auto-generated class?

Comment: have you tried any of the web-based XML to c# applications?

Comment: https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ is a good one

Comment: The first line is the XML prolog, it's not part of the data model, so it shouldn't be present in the class.

Comment: I'll give xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net a try. The generated code looks a bit different to what Visual Studio does. So I can't use it as a dropin replacement. I will modify my code to accommodate it but in my time zone it's already pretty late so I will call it a day and give it tomorrow a try.